# Spring Boot With Kafka on Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile, spring-kafka

I am trying to create an spring boot producer application and I am trying to run it on docker. I have created a docker compose yaml with a simple postgres database and a kafka image. When I am starting the container I am seeing this error message in the broker

```
[2024-02-10 07:41:13,201] INFO [Controller id=1] Skipping preferred replica election for partitions due to topic deletion:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController) 2024-02-10T07:41:13.202837919Z [2024-02-10 07:41:13,201] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Controller 1's connection to broker broker:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread) 2024-02-10T07:41:13.202843669Z java.io.IOException: Connection to broker:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) failed. 2024-02-10T07:41:13.202845419Z    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:70) 2024-02-10T07:41:13.202854544Z    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:298) 2024-02-10T07:41:13.202856336Z    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:251) 2024-02-10T07:41:13.202857794Z     at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:127)
```

and in the producer application I am seeing this error

```
2024-02-10T07:41:51.769527256Z 2024-02-10T07:41:51.768Z  INFO 1 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-02-10T07:41:51.769663798Z 2024-02-10T07:41:51.769Z  WARN 1 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2024-02-10T07:41:52.803914007Z
```

I am attaching my docker compose yaml and my Dockerfile below. I have just started exploring docker so I am also open to suggestions to improve the docker config that I have written as well.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"


services:
  producer:
    image: "spring-boot-kafka-producer:latest"
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: producer
    depends_on:
      - database
      - broker
      - zookeeper
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=${POSTGRESDB_USER}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${POSTGRESDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=broker:9092
      - spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      - spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
  database:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: database
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRESDB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRESDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRESDB_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_HOST: zookeeper
      ports:
        "2181:2181"

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:latest
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "29093:29093"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://broker:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://157.245.80.232:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://:29093
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:17-jre-latest 
LABEL description="Spring boot producer application to explore the various funtionalities spring offers for kakfa"
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

Comment: The Kafka container is called `broker` not `kafka`. That's the hostname your app needs to connect to. Also, it's possible that the Kafka container hasn't started completely yet when Spring tries to connect

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I actually tried setting it as broker as well in the application environment variable still it gave me the same error. Also I don't think the broker is starting up if you see the first section of the logs :"connection to broker broker:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful " This is the broker logs.